# Create new files from a file inputs in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have some table names in a file called `tables.txt`.

The table names are below

```
123_test
123_testing
123_testing_1
234_test
234_testing
234_testing_1
```

Now I want to create files like below

`test`

```
123_test
234_test
```

`testing`

```
123_testing
234_testing
```

`testing_1`

```
123_testing_1
234_testing_1
```

I tried like below

```
while read -r line ; do 
    echo "$line" >> "${line%%_*}.txt"  
done < tables.txt
```

But I am getting

`123.txt`

```
123_test
123_testing
123_testing_1
```

`234.txt`

```
234_test
234_testing
234_testing_1
```

How can I get the correct result

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for **some** of the reasons you should not be using a shell loop for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` is for removing a suffix, you should use `#` to remove a prefix

```
while read -r line; do
    echo "$line" >> "${line#*_}.txt"
done < tables.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk` command for this job:

```
awk '{fn=$0; sub(/[^_]*_/, "", fn); print >> fn; close(fn)}' file
```

`sub` function will remove starting non-underscore text followed by a underscore.

Comment: You really don't need the leading caret in your regex:- `sub(/[^_]*_/,"",fn)`